# Typescript change property types recursively

Tags: typescript

I have an object that I want to "overwrite" certain types for recursively. This is a contrived example, but in this case, I want to take any type that is a `number` and convert it to a `string`.

```js
type NumbersStringified<O extends Object> = {
  [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends Object ? NumbersStringified<O[K]> : O[K] extends number ? string : O[K];
};

type Original = {
    data1: number,
    data2: boolean,
    data3: string,
    data4: {
        data5: number,
        data6: boolean,
        data7: string
    }
};

const converted: NumbersStringified<Original> = {
    data1: 'a',
    data2: false,
    data3: '',
    data4: {
        data5: 'a',
        data6: false,
        data7: ''
    }
};
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIByBXAtgI1gJwM4GVwsBLAOwHMiAzI2AEwB4B5eWAD3FhNp3kfQCtYAY3AA%20eAF54Ab1Dx4AbQDS8UvADWsSAHtKvALoAuXsv0t2nbrwHDw8APxI0mXAWLkqNBo1PjjPpTM2Di4eEmdsB3gcQlIyeH9TAG5QAF8UsBAoOF5iChIAQwAbSRk5eXhaAvACgEZjcIxsABpy%20SqagCZjdG1tItgCklaQCsrqgoBmYxj3MhGxjoKAFmNZUbGKpYBWBoisBc32iYA2Hr6BocOjpYB2GdjyNvhUtIzQIW0SGPhPkgA3bAcWjGFBNVyPCjUOhMPKkYriKTrRYTerwADkBXR13GXWMlGKOFgOKW0wx2OeS1WZQ2NwmuwxWJxKJqZ3gBKKROZWwm93Jz1eIHSoBFICAA)

In this example, I am expecting/wanting `data1` and `data5` to be strings but TS still thinks they should be a `number`. Does anyone know why the pattern of `O[K] extends number ? string` does not match `data1` and `data2`?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Object` type [does not mean what you think it means](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object).  It refers to any type that can be indexed into like an object.  This includes [auto-wrapped primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript).  For example, `string` extends `Object` because, for example, `"hello".toUpperCase()` is allowed.  Essentially only `null` and `undefined` do not extend `Object`.  And that means your `NumbersStringified` type is pretty much a no-op; if `O[K]` is a `number` then `O[K] extends Object` and you never even reach the part where `number` is replaced with `string`.

If you want to refer to non-primitives, you should use [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) (note the difference in case).

---

That being said, you could write `NumbersStringified` without referring to `Object` or `object` at all, since [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) will automatically behave like an identity function for primitives (e.g., `string` goes in, `string` comes out):

```
type NumbersStringified<T> = T extends number ? string : {
    [K in keyof T]: NumbersStringified<T[K]>
};
```

This is much simpler and gives you the behavior you want, at least for your example:

```
type N = NumbersStringified<Original>
/* type N = {
    data1: string;
    data2: boolean;
    data3: string;
    data4: {
        data5: string;
        data6: boolean;
        data7: string;
    };
} */

const converted: NumbersStringified<Original> = {
    data1: 'a',
    data2: false,
    data3: '',
    data4: {
        data5: 'a',
        data6: false,
        data7: ''
    }
}; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIByBXAtgI1gJwM4GVwsBLAOwHMiAzI2AEwB4AVAPngF55H5YAPcWErRzwSaTFngB+eDkKky8AFzwA3qHgb4AbQDS8UvADWsSAHtKnALrKUGbPjnkqNBo12XmoAL4BuUBBgEAHliChIAQwAbdlV1TVpw8HCARmVROywAGjiNBKSAJmV0U1NI2HCSbJBNeDzwgGZlWWJyKpq6gBZlNWqa+MTwgFY0sWw2vtyBgDYikrKK8Ym6gHYmxzIc+C9vPzAQKDgkGNtxBxaKajp6EKIwqM8QAHoAKngDhEQYnvaB1Jl13Y-AqzUrlEiA-pJRr-c4QyZJLqxXpLAbDGHyOF9OozeDFUEVTFA8KrdHkTG+bzwZ6PfwgADGphIsngDJIADdsPxaDZRrgCOdnFcbndIqwON9ISllABycLSxa1AaFeCUKI4WAKurQ6XyzadbqbIlo2W65FY6bKVWRdUKokknWbbYgXxAA)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Object` instead of `object`, so it's actually expecting the literal `Object` global. Changing it will make it work:

```
type NumbersStringified<O extends object> = {
  [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends object ? NumbersStringified<O[K]> : O[K] extends number ? string : O[K];
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4GcDKxUEsB2A5rgGa4QAmAPAPJQQAewE+F6UA9kgFYQDGwAHxQAvFADeAWABQUKAG0A0lAJQA1hBAcSUGgF0AXLqV76TFm049+wKAH5YiFBmx4ipctRonhR74tNGZlZ2fCc0eyh0HAJCKD8TAG4ZAF9k6RlQSF08YnwAQwAbUQkZOTkKfOB8gEYjMOQ0ABoy8srqgCYjJA4OQoh8-BbZNqr8gGYjaLdCYfKodvyAFiMpEfmKsYBWevDUOY3N6oA2bt7+wYPDxYB2KZiiVrkU1PSZPg58aKgP-AA3NDMChGeCNFwPYhkSi0XIEIrCMRreaLOpQADk+TRVwWYy6UBIRXQEGxi0m6KxTxx1RWpXWG0WO3RmOxyLGp3xhOJlNZ1Tu5MpL2kaRkIukQA)